# Omitting the indefinite article before countable nouns at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: articles

Why is "a" missing at the beginning of the following sentence.

> Behavioral economic perspective views addiction as a consequence of falling victim to decision failures that lead to a preference for the addictive behavior.

The word " perspective" is a countable noun in this sense, so It puzzles me why "a" was dropped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"[perspective](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/perspective)" can be countable and uncountable depending on the definition.

- a particular way of viewing things that depends on one’s experience and personality (countable)
- the ability to consider things in relation to one another accurately and fairly (uncountable)
- the method by which solid objects drawn or painted on a flat surface are given the appearance of depth and distance (uncountable)

This, on the other hand, may be a [zero-marking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-marking_in_English) that appears from the rule:

> - The zero article is also used in instructions and manuals. In such cases, the references in the text are all definite, and thus no distinction between definite and indefinite has to be made.